# Xamarin: display image at real size

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Trying to simply display an image at it's full size, which is bigger then the screen width and height. I do not care because I am developing a page for pinch and pan. So, the image will be off the screen anyways, and I would like to use a bigger image for pinch and pan, and it keeps setting the width to screen width when I just want it to show at real height and width. I've tried absolute layout, relative, and stack, nothing works. Here's my current code:

```
<controls:GestureFrame x:Name="GestureFrameMain">    
    <Image x:Name="ImageMain"/>
</controls:GestureFrame>
```

and in the backend, I simply set the source:

```
ImageMain.Source = Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource.FromUri(new System.Uri(PageParametersImageZoom.Image.BigImageURL));
```

I can verify that the URL has an image that is much larger than the screen size, here's an example of an image that would come back: 
http://www.stage.newser.com/image/1088966-0-20161020082458.jpeg

And as you can see it's much larger than the dimensions of the screen, however, when I set the source, the image appears to be at screen size. I've attached an image of the result on the page, which clearly shows the image being downsized by Xamarin.

[image]

**EDIT** the pinch and pan itself is not the problem. When I pinch/pan the image obviously gets larger and goes off screen. I am talking about the initial load of the page, I would like the image to show at its real size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way I was able to do this was by using a `AbsoluteLayout` and specifying the widhrequest/heightrequest properties on the image.